# To Append Block of HTML code after a specific line using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Im trying to append a Block of html code (that is in a Shell Variable) after a specific line. 
for example :-

```
name="john"
link="www.test.com"
jobname="testjob"

data="<tr>
<td>$name</td>
<td><a href=$link>$link</a></td>
<td>$jobname</td>
<td>Running: <progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
</td>
<td>Running: <progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
</td>
<tr>"

sed '/\<tbody\>/a \\$data' filename
```

filename Contains :-

```
<html>
<tbody>
```

I need to append the Shall Variable contents after  line in filename.
Appreciate the responses.

Comment: Not clear, please do mention your problem more clearly and let us know then?

Comment: I would argue that sed isn't the right tool for this job, for instance you will run into issues with escaping of `$data`. However, try switching the `/` delimiter to something else and use `"` instead: `sed "s^<tbody>^$data^g" filename`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can store `$data` in a file instead of shell variable (a temporary file is ok) you can use `r filename` to read and insert the content:

```
echo $data > temp.html
sed "/<tbody>/ r temp.html" filename
```

See [sed command list](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list) and [less frequently used commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Less-Frequently_002dUsed-Commands) for more details.

Comment: Thank ext !. However i will try to find a solution with Variable.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for s/old/new/, that is all (e.g. see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001) for the horrors involved in trying to get sed to treat a string as a string), and you need to fix your quoting and escaping. Try this (untested):

```
name='john'
link='www.test.com'
jobname='testjob'

data='<tr>
<td>'"$name"'</td>
<td><a href='"$link"'>'"$link"'</a></td>
<td>'"$jobname"'</td>
<td>Running: <progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
</td>
<td>Running: <progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
</td>
<tr>'

awk '
BEGIN {
    data = ARGV[2]
    ARGV[2] = ""
    ARGC--
}
{ print }
/<tbody>/ { print data }
' file "$data"
```